# Is there a Python Library to extract video metadata such as [Title, Description, Caption/Subtitles]?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, html5-video, data-extraction, pyffmpeg

I'm currently trying to find python libraries that can assist me in extracting metadata or information from video files such as [**mp4, Mkv, Avi, WebM, mpg**] formats for example.

The main data that I'm focusing on extracting from the video files are mostly the [**Title, Description, Comment, Captions/Subtitles**].

I've tried using FFmpeg-python following this guide: https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/extract-media-metadata-in-python

and Tinytag, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/access-metadata-of-various-audio-and-video-file-formats-using-python-tinytag-library/

From my understanding, FFmpeg-python provided the most data from the **probe()** function but the output does not contain [**Title, Description, Comment**] and **closed_captions** is simply '0' which I assume is the source track.

Thank you for any help provided.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ffprobe` to get the metadata:

```py
import subprocess as sp
import json
import pprint

out = sp.run(['ffprobe','-of','json','-show_entries', 'format:stream', videofile],\
             stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
results = json.loads(out.stdout)
metadata_format = results['format']['tags']
metadata_streams = [res['tags'] for res in results['streams']]

pprint(metadata_format) # "main" metadata: Title & Description found here
pprint(metadata_streams) # per-stream metadata
```

For the substitles/closed-captions, you need to read the subtitle streams with `ffmpeg`:

```py
# get subtitle in webvtt format
out = sp.run(['ffmpeg','-i',videofile, '-map', 's:0', '-f','webvtt','-'],\
             stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
subtitle = out.stdout
```

Then you can use a library like [`webvtt-py`](https://pypi.org/project/webvtt-py/) to parse the subtitle data. (I don't have firsthand experience, so try it yourself.)

One caveat though. If your video is a DVD rip, then its subtitle streams (dvd_subtitle) are bitmaps and not text, and FFmpeg cannot convert it to a text data.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. I'll try out ffprobe and see how it goes!

Comment: Hi, I've tried it out and it does work, and got what I'm looking for. Just a bit confused regarding how the subprocess.run() function.

From what I understand, it's calling the ffprobe from FFmpeg, and taking in the options of 
[-of:json -> set the output printing format
-show_entries, format:stream -> Set list of entries to show]

While the subtitle sp.run is running ffmpeg with the options of
[-i input_url -> Read input_url.
-f format -> Force format to use.

-map -> choose which streams from the input(s) should be included in the output
's:0' -> select subtitle stream index #0]

Comment: Your on on the money with your interpretation. What's the confusion?

Comment: Nothing else then, Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi, I tried manually adding some texts into the mp4 videos subtitles tag under their properties. I tried pprint(subtitle) but I see blanks instead. Was it supposed to pop out a FFmpeg program or write out a subtitle file? Thank you.

Comment: With a right media player there's no need to process an extracted VTT file by Python again in order to create properly working subtitles. As of January 2024 and 3.0.20 version of VLC Media Player, only creating external VTT file and uploading it into a video manually should suffice: [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/software/comments/whdhyt/media_player_that_correctly_handles_vtt_subtitles/?rdt=51329).